# The meaning of mingle

Tags: slang, phrase-meaning, connotation

If a girl tells you that she is single and ready to mingle, does *mingle* here mean that she is ready to “hook up”? ¹

---

<sub>1. That is, [to have casual sexual intercourse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hookup_culture).</sub>

Comment: You can't really say for sure from this alone. There's just not enough context.

Comment: Very funny @Jay. I am working from 9 am to 6 pm. Second of all the girl has told that in a chat and not to me so I look it up and according to Merriam Webster it means to come into contact (associate) .I was wondering hmm contact two sweat bodies lying one against another is this another word that is hidden synonym of fuck. And third , the most recent computer game I have played was chess. I have one colleague that is very good and I hate to lose. He has won my faculty championship 30 years ago.

Comment: I don't see how this is more "opinion based" than many questions asking about the meaning of an idiomatic phrase.

Comment: It might be wise to ask for a clarification before assuming anything. If the person then describes herself as "unwed and ready to bed," you'll have a clearer sense of her intentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, to "mingle" means to mix or combine. You might say, for example, "The blue and red marbles were mingled together", meaning they were mixed.

It is common to talk of people mingling, meaning that they are spending time with others. E.g., "I'm going to go to Sally's party and mingle with other people" or "He mingled with artists and writers."

"Single and ready to mingle" is a stock phrase meaning that a person is no longer in a committed relationship to one other person and so is now looking for another partner. I thought it was pretty obsolete: I haven't heard it in many years until now.

It does not imply that the person is interested in a one-night-stand. The person MIGHT have that in mind, but the phrase itself simply indicates a willingness to date.

Comment: +1 Jay. Despite all your negative comments you pretty much ace that question. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 8):

It means that the girl is ready to start looking for potential partners again. She is ready to get back into the dating scene and *mingle* with people she is attracted to.

One could imply that her last break up left her reluctant to get back into the dating scene, and being "ready to mingle" means she is over her mourning period.

It does not necessarily mean she is ready to *hook up* (i.e. have sexual intercourse).

This interpretation works for people of any sex, too, not just girls.

Comment: Does "hook up" really mean "have sexual intercourse"? Maybe I'm just a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: @Urbycoz not exclusively, but [yes it does](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hook?q=hook+up#hook__41).

Comment: Well I am still not sure I can put equal sign between hook up and having sex. Does one night stand can be called hook up or not.

Comment: A one night stand is a hook up.

Comment: Do you really have mourning period between two relations in UK? That is ridiculous, a grief for your death relationship ? I usually go out trying to find out one night stand before having time to be alone and think how miserable I am feeling. Fire can be stopped with fire as old people are saying.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has studied psychology, yes. Normal human beings mourn at the end of an important and deeply felt relationship. People mourn in many and varied ways.

Comment: @speedyGonzales I don't claim to be an expert on the latest youth slang, but I think "hook up" pretty much refers ONLY to a short sexual relationship such as a one-night stand. I don't think a marriage would be called a "hook up". I'll gladly defer to anyone more knowledgable about the latest hip jive. :-)